# Converting inches to feet, meters and miles without a decimal

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that asks the user for the total number of inches and converts their value to miles, yards, feet, and inches.  Prompt your user for their input as a whole number of inches.  You may assume that they are well-behaved and can follow instructions so be sure to give them guidance concerning how large their number can be.  Convert their value and output the corresponding number of miles, yards, feet and inches, labeling each value in your output.  For example, if the user inputs

158,430 inches, your output should be something like:

```
     158430 inches corresponds to:

                    2 miles

                    880 yards

                   2 feet

                   6 inches
```

For the same input value, one might argue that your output is correct as:

```
     158430 inches corresponds to:

                    2 miles

                    880 yards

                   1 feet

                   18 inches
```

---

this is what i have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
float inches;
    printf("enter number of inches: ");
    scanf("%f", &inches);

    printf("value in miles is %f", inches/ 63360);
    printf("\nvalue in yards is %f", inches/36);
    printf("\nvalue in feet is %f", inches/12);
    printf("\nvalue in inches is %f", inches);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The `stdio.h` is a C language header not C++.  Which language are your programming in?  I recommend you update the language tags accordingly.

Comment: do the maths first, there is no problem in your code. Maybe consider a similar example: 60 minutes are 1 hour and 0 minutes. According to your logic 60 minutes are 1 hour plus 60 minutes

Comment: [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) allows you to control the number of digits to print beyond the integer part of the numbers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actaully for this exercise OP should better use only integers

Comment: Use `long` and research integer math with `/` and `%`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntactical problem here. Just logical errors. The way you are calculating the individual miles, feet, inches, yards is fine. But the way to find the **remaining** in decreasing order of metric units, is slightly off-logic. You need to calculate how many inches are still remaining after calculating each value in miles, yards, etc.

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
 int inches;
 int miles, yards, feet;
      printf("enter number of inches: ");
     scanf("%d", &inches);
     //calculate miles and then find remaining inches
     miles = inches/ 63360;
     inches = inches - miles*63360;
     //calculate remaining yards and then remaining inches
     yards = inches/ 36;
     inches = inches - yards*36;
     //calculate feet and remaining inches after that
     feet = inches/ 12;
     inches = inches - feet*12;
     printf("%d inches corresponds to: ");
     printf("\n%d miles", miles);
     printf("\n%d yards", yards);
     printf("\n%d feet", feet);
     printf("\n%d inches", inches);

     return 0;
 }
```